# Выпадающий список при редактировании инфы из БД (PHP)

Tags: php, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос о выпадающем списке. Есть две таблицы "Сотрудники" и "Должности". Каждый сотрудник связан с определенной должностью. То-есть это две связных таблицы. Так вот в чем проблема. Делать выпадающий список с данными из БД умею, но вот что-то бы бралось конкретное значение из БД, записывалось в выпадающий список, а затем при изменении, записывалось на которое пользователь изменил, понять не могу.

//выбор сотрудника, информацию по которому мы хотим редактировать

```
   <form method="GET" action="">


<label>Редактировать инофрмацию по сотруднику: </label>
<select name="redakt">
<option value="0"></option> 
            <?php  //выбор сотрудников из существующих
                $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                echo 'successfully entered';
                mysql_select_db('itrem') or die('What is u BD');

                $query="SELECT FIO, ID FROM sotrudniki";
                $res = mysql_query($query);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
            ?>
                <option value="<?=$row['ID']?>" ><?=$row['FIO']?></option>
                    <?
                }
            ?>
```

//после нажатия кнопки "Редактировать" должны появится поля с заполненными данными, которые можно редактировать и потом сохранить. Не получается сделать выпадающий список должностей

```
$query ="SELECT FIO, Nazvanie_d, DateBD, Telefon, DataOfYstr, Nazvanie_ot FROM sotrudniki, Otdel, Dolgnosty WHERE sotrudniki.ID_dolgnosty = Dolgnosty.ID_dolgnosty AND sotrudniki.ID_otdela = Otdel.ID_otdela AND ID = '".$id."'";
    // выполняем запрос
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Ошибка " . mysql_error($link)); 
    //если в запросе более нуля строк
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); // получаем первую строку
        $fio = $row[0];
        $nazvanie_d = $row[1];
        $datebd = $row[2];
        $telefon = $row[3];
        $dataofystr = $row[4];
        $nazvanie_ot = $row[5];

echo "<center><h2>Изменить информацию о отруднике</h2>
        <form method='POST'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' />
        <p>ФИО:<br> 
        <input type='text' name='fio' maxlength='50' value='$fio' /></p>
        <p>Должность:
        <select name='dolgnosty'>
        <option value='0'>'$nazvanie_d'</option>
                                                    <?php
                                        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                                        mysql_select_db('itrem') or die('What is u BD');

                    $query='SELECT Nazvanie_d, ID_dolgnosty FROM Dolgnosty';
                    $res = mysql_query($query);
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                ?>
                    <option value='<?=$row['ID_dolgnosty']?>' ><?=$row['Nazvanie_d']?></option>
                        <?
                    }

        </select><br>

        <input type='submit' value='Сохранить'>
        </form></center>";
```

Answer (score -1):

вы бы сразу писаи что на 48 строке надо

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli $link, string $_GET['ID']);//строка 48
```

заменить на это

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['ID']);//строка 48
```

в документации просто указаны типы значений. Для наглядности и лёгкости восприятия к примеру посмотрел тип `string $oneArgument` значит `$oneArgument` должен быть строкой. А если `array $oneArgument` значит массив, а если `array &$oneArgument` ссылка и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: При изменении на: `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['ID']);//строка 48` выдает ошибку _Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in_

Comment: @NyaFanya Так замените все `mysql_*` на аналогичные `mysqli_*` функции

Comment: Всё изменила, там еще нужно было местами поменять link и Get[ID]. Теперь проблема в том, что нужен выпадающий список, в котором элемент уже выбран

Comment: @NyaFanya Ну во первых где вы храните выбраное значение? во вторых не именуйте переменные скрипты и т.п. транслитом, в третьих не используйте шорт теги. в чётвертых очень просто вс это делается добавляете `if(условие) echo 'checked'` в условие

Comment: Пост исправила для большей наглядности. За транслит знаю-грешна, но так понятнее всего (английский слабый, доучиваю). Шорт-теги использую, только в некоторый переменных не успела. А вот про функцию if если можно, то поподробнее :)

Comment: `if(условие)` это условный оператор, если условие `true` - правда то выполнить, если это не так `false` - то условие переходит в `else`. Давай (может на ты?) так, что должно быть выбрано при загрузке страницы?

Comment: Я сделала выпадающий список, всеми правдами и неправдами. Помог и интернет и форумы. Сейчас в ответ на свой пост кину то, что вышло. Теперь я работаю над перезаписью в таблицу.

Comment: Ok, отпишись что бы я увидел сразу. p.s. Где ты настольку устаревшую инфу откапываешь?

Comment: Комент с моим кодом вверху. Аахахахах, старая инфа? Я просто с PHP и MySQL знакома только неделю. Просто гуглила, брала инфу, и которая работала-оставляла. Я ведь даже не знаю, как должен выглядеть нормальный "не криворукий" скрипт

Comment: А где `insert`? где данные сохраняються?

Comment: Так вот я сейчас этим занимаюсь. Потом еще докину код, если интересно

Comment: ok как разберёшься пиши сюда. p.s. что за надобность с самой разбираться?

Comment: Так не суда же писать со словами "помогите, я установила Notepad, а код не пишется, напишите мне его".   Я вот кстати нашла проблему в коде, выпадающий список есть, но он не привязан в конкретному "сотруднику". Что-то я это упустила

Comment: @NyaFanya я подумал тебя кто то по работе заставляет. сделай hidden поле с id текущего юзера и по нему вяжи.

Comment: Всё, исправила. Теперь допиливаю перезапись в таблицу

Comment: какая работа, если бы, это я всё в универ делаю)

Comment: Всё, редактирование БД прошло успешно, я справилась. УРАААА

Comment: @NyaFanya типо за зачёт :-D

Comment: Нееееет, если бы зачеты так легко делались. Это у меня специальность "Информационные системы" в универе, и я делаю практику по предприятию с БД

Answer (score -1):

Полный код выбора информации по определенному сотруднику методом GET

```
    if(isset($_GET['redakt']))
{   
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    //echo 'successfully entered';
    mysql_select_db('itrem') or die('What is u BD');


    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['redakt'], $link);

    // создание строки запроса
    $query ="SELECT FIO, Nazvanie_d, DateBD, Telefon, DataOfYstr, Nazvanie_ot FROM sotrudniki, Otdel, Dolgnosty WHERE sotrudniki.ID_dolgnosty = Dolgnosty.ID_dolgnosty AND sotrudniki.ID_otdela = Otdel.ID_otdela AND ID = '".$id."'";
    // выполняем запрос
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Ошибка " . mysql_error($link)); 
    //если в запросе более нуля строк
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); // получаем первую строку
        $fio = $row[0];
        $nazvanie_d = $row[1];
        $datebd = $row[2];
        $telefon = $row[3];
        $dataofystr = $row[4];
        $nazvanie_ot = $row[5];



        echo "<center><h2>Изменить информацию о сотруднике</h2>
            <form method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id' />
            <p>ФИО:<br> 
            <input type='text' name='fio' maxlength='50' value='$fio' /></p>
            <p>Должность:
            <select name='dolgnosty'>";


                        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                        mysql_select_db('itrem') or die('What is u BD');



                        $query1='SELECT Nazvanie_d, ID_dolgnosty FROM Dolgnosty';
                        $id_dolgnosti = $row['ID_dolgnosty'];
                        $res = mysql_query($query1);
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['ID_dolgnosty'].'"'.($row['ID_dolgnosty']==$id_dolgnosti?' selected':'').'>'.$row['Nazvanie_d'].'</option>;';
                        }

            echo "</select><br>

            <p>Дата рождения: <br> 
            <input type='date' name='datebd' value='$datebd' /></p>
            <p>Телефон: <br> 
            <input type='int' name='telefon' value='$telefon' /></p>
            <p>Дата официального устройства: <br> 
            <input type='date' name='dataofystr' value='$dataofystr' /></p>
            <p>Отдел:
            <select name='otdel'>
            <option value='0'>'$nazvanie_ot'</option>";

                        $query2='SELECT Nazvanie_ot, ID_otdela FROM Otdel';
                        $id_otdela = $row2['ID_otdela'];
                        $res2 = mysql_query($query2);
                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row2['ID_otdela'].'"'.($row2['ID_otdela']==$id_dolgnosti?' selected':'').'>'.$row2['Nazvanie_ot'].'</option>;';
                        }

            echo "</select><br>


            <input type='submit' name='submit3' value='Сохранить'>
            </form></center>";
```